# Option to autosave R Studio global environment

Tags: r

Is there an option in R Studio to autosave the global environment at specified intervals? I use it for work and although yes, and there are a lot of auto updates that get pushed through to my machine and force a restart.

Yes, I can just save it myself periodically, but call me crazy, I forget to do it now and then when I leave at the end of the workday.

I looked around R options but don't see it listed, and don't see an answer to the question online, other than someone asks and others warn the person why they think it's a bad idea (memory, size of file, etc).

Is there no option to autosave, say, every 60 minutes, at 13:00 everyday, etc?

Comment: It's not a good idea to depend on saving your workspace, because it's very easy to have things in there that are not obvious, and it stops your work from being reproducible.  Write code that can reproduce it and you'll be much better off.  If some objects take a really long time to compute, then explicitly save those objects.  If you crash or reboot, RStudio will reopen scripts as they were even if you didn't save them.

Comment: Is it an option for you to use RStudio Server? Servers don't get restarted randomly and RStudio Server preserves your workspace for the next login. (You can configure RStudio Desktop to save the workspace when quitting.)

Comment: 1st comment - comment that doesn't answer the question and provides unsolicited assistance is.  
2nd comment - Yes I realize that but getting back into a server is not very easy at my employer, and I use R locally on my machine.

Comment: "Is there no option to autosave, say, every 60 minutes, at 13:00 everyday, etc?" I'm pretty sure there isn't. There are just too many good reasons not to do that.

Comment: Could you not simply set Windows (if you're on Windows) to run a script that save the global environment each days at 13:00 with the Scheduler? I'm pretty sure there is no such functionalities with R Studio as explained by the previous comments.

Comment: Thank you Roland and Gainz. I assumed there was no such option, but thanks for essentially confirming it, and offering *something* in the way of solution. Thank you!